# mongoose referencing not working when object_id is string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two mongo collections, one for department and another one for users

```
    var DeptSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Department Name Missing.'
}},{
timestamps: true
});
DeptSchema.plugin(sequenceGenerator, {
field: '_id',
startAt: '0001',
prefix: 'DEPT'
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('departments', DeptSchema);

//User or staff schema definition
var UserSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'User Name Missing.'
},
role: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Role Missing.',
    enum: ['admin', 'sales']
},
passwordHash: String,
passwordSalt: String,
departmentId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: 'Department Id Missing.',
    ref: 'departments'
}
},{
timestamps: true
});
UserSchema.plugin(sequenceGenerator, {
field: '_id',
startAt: '0001',
prefix: 'staff'
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Now i have inserted one document in departments collection with _id as 'DEPT0001' but while registering a user with data

```
    { name: 'rahul agarwal',
      username: 'rahul43',
      password: 'rev@888',
      departmentId: 'DEPT0001',
      role: 'admin' }
```

on postman it gives error

```
    {
"errors": {
    "departmentId": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"DEPT0001\" at path \"departmentId\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"DEPT0001\"",
        "kind": "ObjectID",
        "value": "DEPT0001",
        "path": "departmentId",
        "reason": {
            "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"DEPT0001\" at path \"departmentId\"",
            "name": "CastError",
            "stringValue": "\"DEPT0001\"",
            "kind": "ObjectId",
            "value": "DEPT0001",
            "path": "departmentId"
        }
    }
},
"_message": "users validation failed",
"message": "users validation failed: departmentId: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"DEPT0001\" at path \"departmentId\"",
"name": "ValidationError"}
```

My question should i not use customized _id field for reference, if its feasible, so why I can't reference it.

Comment: Well you did create the problem. `departmentId: {  type:  Schema.Types.ObjectId,` is wrong. If it's a string then it's `type: String`. Since that expects the referenced `_id` in the other model to be the same, then that also needs `_id: String` on it's side. Not a software problem. A you problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn i tried making departmentId as string but then i wasn't able to reference it. It would take any value as departmentId, irrespective it is available in departments collection or not. I want that if anyone enters departmentId that is not part of department collection then it should throw error.

Comment: You "try" by actually changing your code and showing us what you really have. Talk is cheap. The code you presently have is incorrect. What you are being told to do is "correct" the code. See [Issues#568](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/568) this has been closed for years and works for the rest of the world. It's **you** who are doing it wrong.